# How to change images using next and previous buttons?

Tags: java, android

sorry for annoying you but i am in my first step in android programming and need your support 
the question is,
i want to change between photos using next and previous Button 
i have 3 photos in an array 
and 2 button (next and previous )
 put when i started my app. i should press next button twice to change the photo
also in previous i should press it twice to change back
hope someone help me to improve the code  down

```
 public class SabahList extends AppCompatActivity  {
 ImageView img;
 int[] mario = new int[]{R.drawable.image_a,R.drawable.image_b,R.drawable.image_c};
 int n =0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sabah_list);

    img= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

}

public void btu_next(View view) {
    img.setImageResource(mario[n]);
    if(n<2)

        n++;
}

public void btu_prev(View view) {
    img.setImageResource(mario[n]);
    if(n>0)
        n--;
}
}
```

Comment: try to use viewpager

Comment: can u explain? ,sorry

Comment: see this tut http://www.androhub.com/android-image-slider-using-viewpager/

Comment: thanks , but i need to do it using  buttons ( next- prev.) and OnClick method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your logic problem. Your button's function command them set resource first, then increase/decease value, therefore when you click the second time, it will be set as previous increasingly/decreasingly.

```
public void btu_next(View view) {
   if(n < 2)
      n++;

   img.setImageResource(mario[n]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer may helpful to you if you are using normal array added images from drawable

```
 //Your xml like this

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.devobal.quitchet.SabahList"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/previous"
                android:text="previous"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:text="next"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

    //And your Activity like this
        public class SabahList extends AppCompatActivity {
            ImageView imageView2;
            Button previous,next;
            int i=0;
            private int[] textureArrayWin = {R.drawable.star1,R.drawable.star2, R.drawable.star3,};

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_sabah_list);
                imageView2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                previous  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previous);
                next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
                if(i==0){
                    previous.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                if (i==2){
                    next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        imageView2.setImageResource(textureArrayWin[i]);
                        i--;
                        if(i==0){
                            previous.setVisibility(View.GONE);} else{ previous.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
                        if (i==2){
                            next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else{next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)}
                    }
                });

                next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        //if you are loading from bitmap
                        imageView2.setImageResource(textureArrayWin[i]);
                        i++;
                        if(i==0){
                            previous.setVisibility(View.GONE); } else {previous.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); }
                        if (i==2){
                            next.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else{next.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)}
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```